# DjandoRestFramework padronizar endpoints para métodos com permissões diferentes

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

estou utilizando Django 1.10 com a lib DRF. Criei um Endpoint **/api/contact/** e nesse endpoint aplico 2 métodos (GET e POST), sendo que GET só pode ser visualizado com permissão, e POST pode ser requisitado sem permissão. O problema está no padrão da criação dos endpoints. Veja abaixo a criação das viewsets e urls:

views.py

```
class ContactList(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.ContactSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
       model = models.Contact.objects.all()
       serializer = serializers.ContactSerializer(model, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)

class ContactSend(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = serializers.ContactSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
       serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save()
          return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       else:
          return Response({"message":"403 Forbiden"},  status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
```

sac/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^contact/$', views.ContactSend.as_view(), name="contact_send"),
   url(r'^contact/send/$', views.ContactList.as_view(), name="contact_list"),
]
```

Como poderia transforma-lo em um só endpoint, por exemplo "/contact/" para ambos os metodos com essa variação de permissão.

Answer (score 1):

Sobreescrever o metodo `.get_permissions` é uma solução:

```
class ContactView(ListCreateAPIView):

      ...

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            self.permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
        return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```